# ClaimsIdentity NullReferenceException after installing .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, visual-studio-2012

I have an existing .Net 4 solution developed in vs2010, which uses an IIdentity implementation that is used to define the user of the current request. I now want to use vs2012 to continue it's development.

I have opened the solution in vs2012 and set the target framework in properties to be .Net 4. However when I run the solution, I get an exception when the web server is deserializing the GenericIdentity object. The exception occurs in

```
at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.<get_Claims>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity.OnDeserializedMethod
                                                  (StreamingContext context)
```

The cause of the exception seems to be that the property Claims is not initialized.

What I already know:

1. .Net 4.5 updates .Net 4 on the target machine rather than doing a side-by-side install.
2. GenericIdentity is now derived from the new class ClaimsIdentity in .Net 4.5
3. Setting target framework to .Net 4 means that although the code is still running with .NET 4.0, the 4.5 implementation is used under the covers i.e. you can't see the hierarchy in the visual studio object browser but the debugger and reflector shows the derivation.
4. The GenericIdentity.OnDeserializedMethod accesses the ClaimsIdentity Claims property without checking for null, causing the NullReferenceException

One [solution](http://www.logue.com.ar/blog/2007/12/cassini-serializationexception-type-is-not-resolved-for-member/)  I came across involved making my custom Identity object inherit from System.MarshalByRefObject, but the problem is that custom Identity object is provided by a "Single Sign On" .dll that is used across all systems in our organisation. This means I have no access to it to change its inheritance heirachy.

Is there an alternative solution or workaraound for this problem?

Comment: Does this reproduce with .NET 4.5.1 Release Candidate? Download from here --> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39328. If it reproduces, .NET Framework team would like to take a look. Please email us with code sample on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com. Thanks!

Comment: When I get some downtime I will try it with 4.5.1 and let you know the results

Comment: I can confirm that this issue doesn't occur with version 4.5.1

Comment: I ran into this issue. What compounded my problem was that IE wasn't showing the full stacktrace. I had to go into Event Viewer in order to find the two lines about the Claims Identity object. Grrh. My current 'workaround' is to switch to running my app on IIS.

Comment: @janoulle that's exactly what I had to do too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is only occurring when using the inbuilt Visual Studio server, and as we as a team use IIS locally to run our sites in development, we are just going to live with it as I've just spent too much time on it now.

The problem looks to be around object serialization and deserialization following an appDomain transition, but I don't have time to investigate further.

**UPDATE: This problem does not occur with .NET 4.5.1**

Comment: this is a know issue when serializing from 4.0 -> 4.5.x.