# Custom ClaimsIdentity causing exception in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, claims-based-identity

1. Early in the pipeline, using a custom AuthorizationAttribute we are setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal using an extended ClaimsIdentity

   ```
       CustomIdentity identity = new CustomIdentity("Bearer");
       identity.AddClaim(new Claim("customClaim", customClaimValue));
       ...
       ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
       Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
   ```
2. Later in the pipeline we try to get values from our SQL Server 2012 database using EF6

   ```
       var dataList = _repository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Col1 == parameter);
   ```
3. We then get an exception at runtime. The outer exception is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException : The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifest instance

and the inner exception is:

> Unable to find assembly 'OurApp.Authorization.Models, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

where OurApp.Authorization.Models is the namespace and project name where CustomIdentity lives:

```
namespace OurApp.Authorization.Models
{
[Serializable]
public class CustomIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
        ...
}
}
```

The strange thing is that if I set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal to the current WindowsIdentity immediately before going to the data store then the code works fine:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
var dataList = _repository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Col1 == parameter);
```

It seems that EntityFramework needs to know about our CustomIdentity but I have no idea why. I added references in the data access project anyway but it didn't seem to impact.

We made sure that we weren't using WindowsAuthentication to access SQL Server and all our connectionstrings do not use integrated security now but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know why setting a custom ClaimsIdentity is causing this exception in EntityFramework?

Here's the full exception as requested:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled by
>   user code   HResult=-2146233087   Message=The provider did not return
>   a ProviderManifest instance.   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String
>   manifestToken)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>          at OurApp.Module.ViewStore.EntityFramework.InformationViewStore.Get(String
>   userId) in
>   c:\Code\OurApp\OurApp.Module.ViewStore\EntityFramework\InformationViewStore.cs:line
>   156
>          at OurApp.Module.Azure.Api.Hubs.OurAppHub.OnConnected() in c:\Code\OurApp\OurApp.Module.Azure.Api\Hubs\ModuleHub.cs:line 119
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Connect(IHub hub)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipelineModule.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__7(IHub
>   hub)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipelineModule.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__7(IHub
>   hub)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipeline.Connect(IHub hub)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.b__1c(IHub
>   hub)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__2f(IHub
>   instance)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ExecuteHubEvent(IRequest
>   request, String connectionId, Func`2 action)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnConnected(IRequest
>   request, String connectionId)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessStartRequest(HostContext
>   context, String connectionId)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2
>   environment)
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Middleware.HubDispatcherMiddleware.Invoke(IOwinContext
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()   InnerException: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>          HResult=-2146233076
>          Message=Unable to find assembly 'OurApp.Authorization.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>          Source=mscorlib
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
>   assemblyInfo, String name)
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
>   objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
>   Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
>   objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
>   SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
>   record)
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>               at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck,
>   IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>               at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.DeserializeIdentities(String
>   identities)
>               at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext
>   context)
>               at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
>               at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain
>   appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain
>   appDomain, String exePath)
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord
>   record)
>               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)
>               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission)
>               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)
>               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)
>               at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)
>               at System.Xml.XmlConfiguration.XmlReaderSection.get_ProhibitDefaultUrlResolver()
>               at System.Xml.XmlConfiguration.XmlReaderSection.CreateDefaultResolver()
>               at System.Xml.Schema.Parser..ctor(SchemaType schemaType, XmlNameTable nameTable, SchemaNames schemaNames,
>   ValidationEventHandler eventHandler)
>               at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
>               at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(Stream stream, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet
>   schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1
>   schemasAlreadyAdded)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.ComputeSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption
>   dataModel)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.GetSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption
>   dataModel)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.CreateXmlReaderSettings()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader
>   sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption
>   dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification,
>   AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification,
>   ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1&
>   schemaCollection)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption
>   dataModel, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, IList`1&
>   schemaCollection)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.LoadProviderManifest(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String location, Boolean checkForSystemNamespace, Schema&
>   schema)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest..ctor(XmlReader
>   reader)
>               at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderManifest..ctor(String
>   manifestToken)
>               at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.b__f(String
>   s)
>               at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>               at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String
>   versionHint)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String
>   manifestToken)
>          InnerException:

Comment: Which version of EF you are using? EF has nothing to do with Windows Principal. One problem I can think of is, EF EDMX based model does not work correctly if model is loaded from referenced dll. This is actually your application which is unable load assembly into its appDomain due to restrictions.

Comment: I think it's premature to say that "EntityFramework needs the Thread.CurrentPrincipal set to the current WindowsIdentity identity".  Probably it needs to be able to load the assembly containing the Type that's set as `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.  Posting more details, e.g. the full exception including stack trace might help, as might the assembly binder log.

Comment: Thanks Akasha & Joe for your feedback. The version of EF is 6.1.1. Yes, I think you're right that EntityFramework needs to be able to load the assembly containing the Type that's set in the Thread.CurrentPrincipal, our CustomIdentity above. I'm just not sure where how how to do that. Than0sk again.

Comment: After further digging I came across the following articles [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091534/claimsidentity-nullreferenceexception-after-installing-net-4-5), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693262/serialization-exception-in-net-4-5), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313243/how-to-solve-must-be-marshalbyrefobject-in-a-good-but-multiple-inheritance-amp), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539557/type-cant-be-resolve-in-unittest-after-migrating-project-from-vs2005-to-vs2010). I think I'm closer but still no solution. I've update to .Net 4.5.1.

Comment: I was going to try to use 'MarshalByRefObject' to see if that would work but I really need to my CustomIdentity to inherit from ClaimsIdentity.